# ESP32 MQTT with TLS

Tags: mqtt, tls1.2, esp32, mosquitto

I am currently trying to implement MQTT with TLS. The Mosquitto MQTT-Broker works fine, I can also subscribe/publish from Python, Linux-Shell and also with the Windows-Tools MQTT-Box. When I try to connect to the MQTT-Broker from an ESP32 with TLS I get the following error on the ESP:

```
Certificate verification failed, e.g. CRL, CA or signature check failed
```

In the logfile of the Mosquitto-MQTT-Broker I get the following error:

```
OpenSSL Error: error:14094412:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad certificate
```

Summarized Code on the ESP32:

```
WiFiClientSecure secureClient;
PubSubClient client(secureClient);
secureClient.setCACert(mosq_cert);
client.setServer(mqtt_server, 8883);
client.setCallback(callback);
client.connect(clientId.c_str())
```

The cert looks like this (created with OpenSSL):

```
    const char* mosq_cert = \
"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" \
"MIIFtTCCA52gAwIBAgIUK5VYs14dyCApkwl0eKBp2/Tt5dswDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEN\n" \
"BQAwajEXMBUGA1UEAwwOQW4gTVFUVCBicm9rZXIxFjAUBgNVBAoMDU93blRyYWNr\n" \
"cy5vcmcxFDASBgNVBAsMC2dlbmVyYXRlLUNBMSEwHwYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFhJub2Jv\n" \
"ZHlAZXhhbXBsZS5uZXQwHhcNMjAxMjA5MTIzMjU3WhcNMzIxMjA2MTIzMjU3WjBq\n" \
"MRcwFQYDVQQDDA5BbiBNUVRUIGJyb2tlcjEWMBQGA1UECgwNT3duVHJhY2tzLm9y\n" \
"ZzEUMBIGA1UECwwLZ2VuZXJhdGUtQ0ExITAfBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWEm5vYm9keUBl\n" \
"eGFtcGxlLm5ldDCCAiIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggIPADCCAgoCggIBAL5CDqte\n" \
"kUzk75gYwgijZ1qzW962FSmtNntE1xONg2r2qsOgZoebNlTVJhy84OpiY+BV9wO9\n" \
"JsJKg8xt1S5a85t2xk2reaesKr4bYz8QEzWtffKXyJ2Giv5zQF7hxsyhsamQ3IxU\n" \
"y6CcILxFS2Ig5ZSAvPNX7Hz1AtUpLAewu70Wyr+nSO318UnMVwczsotV0GTqI9KZ\n" \
"4qZRhhEzRkYtk1HegqJ1k4QIKCktTCre4uW9r14NwB6q+Bei8Tz19jM0ubGjZX77\n" \
"OYJY5LjWABNeYPi9aNDFs7cF7LqxPNsFT2z/Vj/qSg/5ISlhPs6PqG2shmZhbl8l\n" \
"nD4SfdKfJM6Zt3HpFuk1UyyXyBrscsaxKK99dbGrvul3iv+LyGBw2KQw3MsbZrqo\n" \
"o4sXLvz9TReZPqUZsfHj1mwU+dl6hV3Zg8I/E/gc9dIQibjRHAXxAZl/rR/UAkw8\n" \
"HqqntiX5zid8bJ1vaYvJ5WFoAZPelDWrWLKOem4gy6h7+yeqXbAbcu8W2B89vG3k\n" \
"yE674ZKTsJ6vnchJqUGylrjbtieHI3hRL7vYhqKgbIuFZHZIFM1uBcOVptNL0yNp\n" \
"y2wL3xEMuElO5hJtmQMoobA8x5VfO5DWvNXa6vCv0OhXmXKq1k3rNfoInwEDi6Sg\n" \
"wJsyj9ig0IQTKP7kpyoO3sU5e7DXoJRf22vJAgMBAAGjUzBRMB0GA1UdDgQWBBTu\n" \
"jgPMXmq0vJKREyEp7TK2d05bVjAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBTujgPMXmq0vJKREyEp7TK2\n" \
"d05bVjAPBgNVHRMBAf8EBTADAQH/MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBDQUAA4ICAQB+IGnyMcVA\n" \
"C1P+s5KDAmKI0SLP0b2jHuoTNq4O91lUjywhjgq81fVUu7WDBZhrvah5u1DPemev\n" \
"OypBYA9HIOYUuOKVXDivcKvP4C1+g9lOnrV9NMp66KHTZHCfBxgPmzxS9jGuJJgX\n" \
"nrs+XiJNNRFRFX76OlgXDjP3wIBSZ/00BBNLW1tt4Ti8LokuwM/gKfrSZDjbBkNC\n" \
"Jq3KZyL6pFcV7C9Xec4wl9Q9+2SE85WlZojoBCx7ElANDnt7YkRHKepb0vjsb7ZG\n" \
"xfHnHCS4yQPT/TLtwkDsvJe2tm/SkxFB2MfB7+tWV+/21YuFQpNaRHZXwLa/mZNG\n" \
"+qii1SGnBpBUl6YgTFA++mQqwEkxQGhrFf2FugdkzxAyQfGzvfIMcichMFS5uRgB\n" \
"+Z4ShbsvIjPiQN97QOS516M6+aUywrEStdzkacwoA443pXxJxCim6lTQMe2nT01F\n" \
"kOTd6yGLFkxWnOPIJCw9VsPCyRsUkJhqvAGrWsm8IT6BZcCPcvHYO8q7/u0g6if1\n" \
"RHfX7LIZdB5f0NLmQedgyte70byjRGFVNfzHP65oYbuNCTFpPdJ1CMg/HXDNxYNd\n" \
"v/NTKIYsanoPeHZgp/6lX44NVIaoU9uNEpr+GePgfE/+r+OoIG2nx2zgcvhJAdjF\n" \
"pXVIrrNIAF3BIGK1Qop/KK+gaY/L8d+raQ==\n" \
"-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";
```

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65218865/edit) the question show the code you are using to set up the connection on the ESP32. Also include information about the certificate you are using on the broker.

Comment: I think this should be fine now....only got code that connects to the WLAN with smart config and that's basically it

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer, I didn't to see the certificate, but I wanted to know if you were generating your own self signed certificates or using one supplied by a public CA and where the certificate you are passing in as a CA cert came from.

Comment: Generated the certificate with the following shell-script: https://github.com/owntracks/tools/blob/master/TLS/generate-CA.sh

Answer (score 0):

try adding a **\r** before the **\n**

```c
const char* mosq_cert = \
"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\r\n" \
"MIIFtTCCA52gAwIBAgIUK5VYs14dyCApkwl0eKBp2/Tt5dswDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEN\r\n" \
"BQAwajEXMBUGA1UEAwwOQW4gTVFUVCBicm9rZXIxFjAUBgNVBAoMDU93blRyYWNr\r\n" \
"cy5vcmcxFDASBgNVBAsMC2dlbmVyYXRlLUNBMSEwHwYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFhJub2Jv\r\n" \
"ZHlAZXhhbXBsZS5uZXQwHhcNMjAxMjA5MTIzMjU3WhcNMzIxMjA2MTIzMjU3WjBq\r\n" \
"MRcwFQYDVQQDDA5BbiBNUVRUIGJyb2tlcjEWMBQGA1UECgwNT3duVHJhY2tzLm9y\r\n" \
"ZzEUMBIGA1UECwwLZ2VuZXJhdGUtQ0ExITAfBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWEm5vYm9keUBl\r\n" \
"eGFtcGxlLm5ldDCCAiIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggIPADCCAgoCggIBAL5CDqte\r\n" \
"kUzk75gYwgijZ1qzW962FSmtNntE1xONg2r2qsOgZoebNlTVJhy84OpiY+BV9wO9\r\n" \
"JsJKg8xt1S5a85t2xk2reaesKr4bYz8QEzWtffKXyJ2Giv5zQF7hxsyhsamQ3IxU\r\n" \
"y6CcILxFS2Ig5ZSAvPNX7Hz1AtUpLAewu70Wyr+nSO318UnMVwczsotV0GTqI9KZ\r\n" \
"4qZRhhEzRkYtk1HegqJ1k4QIKCktTCre4uW9r14NwB6q+Bei8Tz19jM0ubGjZX77\r\n" \
"OYJY5LjWABNeYPi9aNDFs7cF7LqxPNsFT2z/Vj/qSg/5ISlhPs6PqG2shmZhbl8l\r\n" \
"nD4SfdKfJM6Zt3HpFuk1UyyXyBrscsaxKK99dbGrvul3iv+LyGBw2KQw3MsbZrqo\r\n" \
"o4sXLvz9TReZPqUZsfHj1mwU+dl6hV3Zg8I/E/gc9dIQibjRHAXxAZl/rR/UAkw8\r\n" \
"HqqntiX5zid8bJ1vaYvJ5WFoAZPelDWrWLKOem4gy6h7+yeqXbAbcu8W2B89vG3k\r\n" \
"yE674ZKTsJ6vnchJqUGylrjbtieHI3hRL7vYhqKgbIuFZHZIFM1uBcOVptNL0yNp\r\n" \
"y2wL3xEMuElO5hJtmQMoobA8x5VfO5DWvNXa6vCv0OhXmXKq1k3rNfoInwEDi6Sg\r\n" \
"wJsyj9ig0IQTKP7kpyoO3sU5e7DXoJRf22vJAgMBAAGjUzBRMB0GA1UdDgQWBBTu\r\n" \
"jgPMXmq0vJKREyEp7TK2d05bVjAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBTujgPMXmq0vJKREyEp7TK2\r\n" \
"d05bVjAPBgNVHRMBAf8EBTADAQH/MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBDQUAA4ICAQB+IGnyMcVA\r\n" \
"C1P+s5KDAmKI0SLP0b2jHuoTNq4O91lUjywhjgq81fVUu7WDBZhrvah5u1DPemev\r\n" \
"OypBYA9HIOYUuOKVXDivcKvP4C1+g9lOnrV9NMp66KHTZHCfBxgPmzxS9jGuJJgX\r\n" \
"nrs+XiJNNRFRFX76OlgXDjP3wIBSZ/00BBNLW1tt4Ti8LokuwM/gKfrSZDjbBkNC\r\n" \
"Jq3KZyL6pFcV7C9Xec4wl9Q9+2SE85WlZojoBCx7ElANDnt7YkRHKepb0vjsb7ZG\r\n" \
"xfHnHCS4yQPT/TLtwkDsvJe2tm/SkxFB2MfB7+tWV+/21YuFQpNaRHZXwLa/mZNG\r\n" \
"+qii1SGnBpBUl6YgTFA++mQqwEkxQGhrFf2FugdkzxAyQfGzvfIMcichMFS5uRgB\r\n" \
"+Z4ShbsvIjPiQN97QOS516M6+aUywrEStdzkacwoA443pXxJxCim6lTQMe2nT01F\r\n" \
"kOTd6yGLFkxWnOPIJCw9VsPCyRsUkJhqvAGrWsm8IT6BZcCPcvHYO8q7/u0g6if1\r\n" \
"RHfX7LIZdB5f0NLmQedgyte70byjRGFVNfzHP65oYbuNCTFpPdJ1CMg/HXDNxYNd\r\n" \
"v/NTKIYsanoPeHZgp/6lX44NVIaoU9uNEpr+GePgfE/+r+OoIG2nx2zgcvhJAdjF\r\n" \
"pXVIrrNIAF3BIGK1Qop/KK+gaY/L8d+raQ==\r\n" \
"-----END CERTIFICATE-----\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this next time, it is easier to copy and past, won't occupy your heap (PROGMEM saves it on flash) and it will work just the same

```cpp
const char test_ca[] PROGMEM = R"=====(
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
)=====";
```